# Objects Moving Away from Design When Resizing Window in Responsive Design

Tags: css, responsive-design

I'm trying to create my first responsive design tonight, and I'm running into some issues when resizing my page. Everything seems to respond correctly except for the number below the large icon, and the small icons on the bottom right of the page. Both seem to "run away" from the rest of the design when it's not at full size, and the buttons on the bottom right side of the page expose what should be hidden (the hover state of the button). Any ideas on how to fix this?

The site is located here: [removed, solved my own problem]

Comment: I should add that I've only tested this in the latest version of Firefox, so it may not work in other browsers (I assume Chrome and Safari will render it fine but haven't checked yet).

Comment: I think it may be because your mixing pixel dimensions with percentages .. for example the height of the martini pushes down the number when you re-size to smaller.

Comment: You're correct Richard. Luckily this isn't going to be a fully functioning app, but if it were I'd have to make adjustments to the layout so I wouldn't have to specify any heights. Since this is mainly for mockups, I've just made the number part of the background graphic for the main circle and made the bar across the bottom fixed size. Not completely responsive, but somewhat.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add this for every  you make:

position:relative;
z-index:1;

That's for control every  so it won't resize others